# MySQL messages model query + last in group

Tags: mysql, sql, database

Here is my simpled messages DB

```
id | from_id | to_id | created_at
```

So i have query to get dialogs list (here i get only coll from results- the last id of last message with collocutor):

```
SELECT IF(to_id = #{id}, from_id, to_id) as coll,
       LEAST(from_id,to_id), 
       GREATEST(from_id, to_id), 
       MAX(created_at), 
       MAX(id) FROM `messages`  
WHERE LEAST(from_id,to_id) = #{id} or GREATEST(from_id, to_id) = #{id}
GROUP BY LEAST(from_id,to_id), GREATEST(from_id, to_id)
ORDER BY MAX(created_at) DESC
```

From this query i've got list of last messages with every collocutors. Now I need to get all last messages id's with every collocutors where last message was FROM collocutor to ME. The first idea was to join messages table by MAX(id). So the code was born:

```
SELECT IF( m1.to_id = #{id}, m1.from_id, m1.to_id ) AS coll,
       LEAST( m1.from_id, m1.to_id ) ,       
       GREATEST( m1.from_id, m1.to_id ) , 
       MAX( m1.created_at ) , 
       MAX( m1.id )
FROM  `messages` AS m1 
INNER  JOIN messages AS m2 on m2.id = MAX( m1.id )
WHERE  (
         LEAST( m1.from_id, m1.to_id ) = #{id}
         OR GREATEST( m1.from_id, m1.to_id ) = #{id}
       )
       AND
       m2.from <> #{id}
GROUP BY LEAST( m1.from_id, m1.to_id ) , GREATEST( m1.from_id, m1.to_id ) 
ORDER BY MAX( m1.created_at ) DESC
```

But is rises #1111 error. The second idea was "Hmmm, actually I need to join second messages table to result of first query". So now was born monkey code:

```
Select * from (SELECT IF(to_id = #{id}, from_id, to_id) as coll,
       LEAST(from_id,to_id), 
       GREATEST(from_id, to_id), 
       MAX(created_at), 
       MAX(id) as max_id
FROM `messages`  
WHERE LEAST(from_id,to_id) = #{id} or GREATEST(from_id, to_id) = #{id}
GROUP BY LEAST(from_id,to_id), GREATEST(from_id, to_id)
ORDER BY MAX(created_at) DESC) m1
LEFT JOIN messages as m2 on m1.max_id = m2.id
WHERE to_id =#{id}
```

So, that's working. But what about optimizing? Have any ideas for it?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not getting last message ID from "core" query. I'm getting last collocutor id in IF( m1.to_id = #{id}, m1.from_id, m1.to_id ) :)

Comment: please provide some sample data and desired output. sqlfiddle is more comfortable